# Can somebody help to identify my mistake; I don't understand why this code fails to pass the test case

Tags: python

The main task is to write a rudimentary BMI calculation function called compute_bmi() that reads in that order, the user's height (in meter) and weight (in kilogram), and returns a string that shows the body type of the user:

```
1.  "Under" : if the BMI is lower than 18.5 (exclusive)
2.  "Normal": if the BMI is higher than 18.5 (inclusive) but lower than 25 (exclusive)
3.  "Over": if the BMI is higher than 25 (inclusive) but lower than 35 (exclusive)
4.  "Obese": if the BMI is higher than 35 (inclusive)
```

Suppose that the height is `1.7 (meters)` and weight is `68 (kilograms)`, function call `compute_bmi()` will read `1.7` and `68` from keyboard and then return string `"Normal"`. In addition, the height and weight should be converted to float type. For this particular task, the server will read data from keyboard using `input()`, and that the `compute_bmi()` function is supposed to return a string instead of printing it on screen.

I have included the `try-exception block` code to avoid a division of 0 if the value of the height is equal to `0`.

My code:

```py
def compute_bmi():
    
    BMI = weight / (height **2)

    if BMI < 18.5:
        return('Under')

    elif 18.5 <= BMI < 25:
        return('Normal')

    elif 25 <= BMI <35:
        return('Over')

    else:
        return('Obese')

height = float(input("Enter height in m: "))
weight = float(input("Enter weight in kg: "))

if height <= 0 or weight <= 0:
    print("Please enter a valid number.")
    
else:
    try:
        print(compute_bmi())
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number.")
```

I've tried numerous times rewriting the code in a different format, but still it fails to pass the test case.

The test case:

```
Expression                           Expected   
check_bmi(['1.7','68'])              'Normal'   
check_bmi(['1.7', '100'])            'Over'
```

In my opinion, I believe there could be some inherent errors in the test case, since they're using the function `check_bmi` rather than the original function which is stated `compute_bmi`. On the flipside, it is possible that the test case is testing some other aspect of the function that is not covered by the code provided, or there might be some mistake in the test cases that you are using to test the function, and the expected output of the function is different from the output I am seeing.

Comment: where is this function `check_bmi()`?

Comment: I don't really know but it's stated in the test case. I presume the server might have made an error from their side.

Comment: if testcase is like this `check_bmi(['1.7','68']) ` you need to change the function name by giving two parameters like `def check_bmi(height,weight):` also no need of input taking from the users. .

Comment: What’s the reported error exactly?

Comment: Looks like the function *check_bmi()* takes a list of strings. Is that what you're trying to impliment?

Comment: Also you are taking a list as an input parameter

Comment: FWIW, you don’t need to recheck already failed conditions. `if BMI < 18.5` is false, you don’t need to test `18.5 <= BMI` again in the next case.

Comment: I've tried changing the original function from compute_bmi() to check_bmi. I've tried to run this code but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: the original function that they'd want to implement is compute_bmi()

Comment: @programming_is_fun : *If the script is used in an external run test procedure* the core of the problem may be the that your script code does not implement the right interface for the used test procedure. **Check out carefully** again how you have to write the code to be suitable for usage in the test procedure. **There have to be detailed instructions there.** Most probably the test procedure pass height/weight on the command line to the script and you must get the values with `import sys; height=sys.argv[1]; weight=sys.argv[2]` and output the result to stdout with `print()`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to pass 2 parameters in the function for height and weight

You are taking 2 inputs from the user and converting them to float. Later those inputs are passed to `compute_bmi(a,b)` via `compute_bmi(height,weight)` and you are getting the return from this function.

This should be the code:

```
def compute_bmi(a,b):
    
    BMI = weight / (height **2)

    if BMI < 18.5:
        return('Under')

    elif BMI < 25:
        return('Normal')

    elif BMI < 35:
        return('Over')

    else:
        return('Obese')

height = float(input("Enter height in m: "))
weight = float(input("Enter weight in kg: "))

if height <= 0 or weight <= 0:
    print("Please enter a valid number.")
    
else:
    try:
        print(compute_bmi(height,weight))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number.")
```

When you take input from user:

```
Enter height in m: 1.7
Enter weight in kg: 68
Normal

Enter height in m: 1.7
Enter weight in kg: 100
Over
```

Comment: I believe this answer is correct, but it still fails to pass the test case after running the code.

Comment: Even though it’s better to pass parameters, in this case it did happen to work without doing so as well. And you’re not even using the parameters.

Comment: @programming_is_fun Don’t accept the answer if it doesn’t solve your problem.

Comment: if your function takes parameter with a variable name `a` and `b` you should replace `height` `weight` with a and b also..

Comment: @programming_is_fun I am not able to get what you are saying. I will edit my code according to your need. Do you want to pass a list as an input parameter?

Comment: @Claudio `elif 18.5 <= BMI` < 25: to `elif BMI < 25` is implemented now.

Comment: @God Is One, I suppose it's not really a list. I've tried multiple times rewriting the code, and it seems that none of them work. Personally, I think there's an error in the test case from their end.  But it's okay. I'm thankful for the fact that you're helping out.

Comment: @programming_is_fun : from what you say *(the script is used in an external run test procedure)* the core of the problem may be the that your script code does not implement the right interface for the used test procedure. **Check out carefully** again how you have to write the code to be suitable for usage in the test procedure. **There have to be detailed instructions there.** For example the test can pass height/weight on the command line to the script and you must get the values with `import sys; height=sys.argv[1]; weight=sys.argv[2]` and print the result along with returning the value.